# A {"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."}

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Basically when I run this code, I get the following error and I don't know how to resolve it. I get this error when I click on button then I am redirected back  to Visual Studio with the following error. Please help me solve this error, help is appreciated.

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this command which must be closed first.

```
public partial class forgot : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void resetpass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from reg where Username =@username", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@security1", sec1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@security2", sec2.Text);

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)
        {
            newpass.Visible = true;
            confpass.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "New Password";
            Label2.Text = "Confirm New Password";

            SqlDataAdapter updates = new SqlDataAdapter("update reg set Password='" + newpass.Text + "'", con);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            updates.Fill(ds);

            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('The Password has been Changed')</script>");
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Fill` method will automatically `open` connection, and before that you should `Close` previous connection.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Why are you editing out your code?

Comment: Your repeated editing out of your code is considered vandalism.  Why do you persist in doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time you attempt to run `Fill`, the connection `con` is already busy trying to retrieve data to keep the `SqlDataReader` happy.  A database connection can only handle one resultset at a time.

You have two options:

1. Initialize `updates` with a second database connection instance, so you will have two open at the same time.
2. Use `reader` to get the complete resultset first, storing it in an array or DataTable.  Then, when you are done with the reader, iterate through the array/table and perform the updates to reg.

Comment: can you please edit the code please with first option

Comment: I did try your second way the error disappeared buy why is letting the user to video newpass.Visible = true;
                confpass.Visible = true;       and etc.. when the if statement is not met because I want the username.text = username, security questions to be equal to database security questions. when these conditions are met then it should display the content in if statement

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because you have nested data readers. Here is your code, simplified, to show what you are doing:

```
protected void resetpass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   // Here is data reader
   SqlDataReader reader = null;
   // ...
   reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   if( reader != null && reader.HasRows ) {
      // ...
      // and here is another one within the above data reader
      SqlDataAdapter updates = new SqlDataAdapter( "update reg set Password='" + newpass.Text + "'", con );
   }
}
```

To do that, you need to enable [MARS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfa084cz(v=vs.110).aspx). You can do so in your connection string:

```
Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;
  MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

Of course you that is just an example, you will need to use your own connection string.

Answer (score 1):

the error said that you have opened `DataReader` and you opened another `SqlDataAdapter` before closing `DataReader`. So in .Net you need to close the first command in order to open a new command.

change this:

```
 if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)
        {
            newpass.Visible = true;
            confpass.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "New Password";
            Label2.Text = "Confirm New Password";
            SqlDataAdapter updates = new SqlDataAdapter("update reg set Password='" + newpass.Text + "'", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            updates.Fill(ds);
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('The Password has been Changed')</script>");
            con.Close();
        }
```

to

```
 if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)
        {
            reader.Close();
            newpass.Visible = true;
            confpass.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "New Password";
            Label2.Text = "Confirm New Password";
            SqlDataAdapter updates = new SqlDataAdapter("update reg set Password='" + newpass.Text + "'", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            updates.Fill(ds);
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('The Password has been Changed')</script>");
            con.Close();
        }
```